# sufficient conditions for solution

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the square matrix equation (all matrices of dimension $n \times n$):

$G \Lambda G' = \Sigma$ where $\Lambda$ and $\Sigma$ are diagonal (with positive values on the diagonal). Under what sufficient conditions are the only solutions for $G$ equal

$G = \Sigma^{1/2} V \Lambda^{-1/2}$ for a $V$ such that $VV' = I$?

Comment: The line breaks look a bit as if you tried to get those equations to be displayed -- are you aware that you can get displayed equations using double dollar signs?

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply by $\Sigma^{-1/2}$ from left and right. The result can be written $VV'=I$ with $V=\Sigma^{-1/2}G\Lambda^{1/2}$, which yields your equation when solved for $G$, so there's no need for further conditions.